# Format telephone number binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

How can I format a telephone number like the following using knockout?

```
<a href="tel:12345679">
    call us
</a>
```

My attempt:

```
<a data-bind="attr:{'href:tel':telephone}">call us</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it now:

```
<a data-bind="attr:{'href': 'tel:'+telephone()}">call us</a>
```